# Azure AAD B2C Sample API Issue

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I have an issue with the Azure sample AAD B2C API (all the steps are followed) - code taken from: [AAD B2C](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-tutorial/tree/main/3-Authorization-II/2-call-api-b2c) 
Note: Also tested with another sample AAD code: [AAD](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-tutorial/blob/main/3-Authorization-II/1-call-api/README.md) and it worked without any issues.

The issue (issue for AAD B2C) is on the API and when I try to connect to the localhost of the api, the following error pops up:
[image]
I don't understand what I am missing ? 
Thank you

Comment: Please include your [mre] code as text here in the post. Links will rot over time.

Comment: It's weird because in the sample that was showing, appeared with the links and image....

Comment: The links are code samples from microsoft. I didn't add anything special, just the steps that they recommended to change.

Comment: according to your description, it must be somewhere you misconfigured. could you pls check if you set correct value in `appsettings.json` and some other places?

Comment: Yes it was from the appsettings, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is from the appsettings, but I was misguided from the steps that I was following from the AAD B2C link.
In the page says:
"Find the key Instance and replace the existing value with your Azure AD B2C tenant name."
"Find the key Domain and replace the existing value with your Azure AD B2C tenant name."
So in my case I was just adding the names of the tenant.

In the appsettings the correct way is:

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://TENANT-NAME.b2clogin.com/",
    "ClientId": "ID from the App registration of the API",
    "Domain": "TENANT-NAME.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_user_flow",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "B2C_1_edit_user_flow"
  }
```

Thank you Tiny Wang for the guidance.